# Голосовой помощник даёт ошибку

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, pyttsx3, google-speech-recognition

Голосовой помощник принимает мой голос, но потом даёт ошибку: "Голос не распознан"

File "D:\pythonу\friday.py", line 41, in callback
cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)

File "D:\pythonу\friday.py", line 52, in recognize_cmd
RC = {'cmd': '', percent: 0}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]NameError: name 'percent' is not defined

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Очевидно, вы используете несуществующую переменную `percent`, больше здесь сказать нечего